# TMG Matlab Error

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

when I connect MATLAB & MYSQL ,the Error is

> > init_tmg ================================================================================================== ================================================================================================== You are about to installed the TMG Toolbox to you system. Press any key to continue! ================================================================================================== ================================================================================================== Is MATLAB Database Toolbox installed (yes/no)?: yes Is MySQL installed (yes/no)?: yes Please give the full path to the MySQL Java Connector (jar file): C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.23\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar ??? Error using ==> fprintf Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

```
Error in ==> init_tmg at 36 fid=fopen(strcat(matlabroot, filesep, 'toolbox', filesep, 'local', filesep, 'classpath.txt'), 'a'); fprintf(fid, '\n%s', str); fclose(fid);
```

How can I Deal with this Error????

Comment: Run `dbstop if error`and check what  - I imagine that `fid  = -1` - i.e. MATLAB could not open the file `classpath.txt`, either because the path to the file is wrong, or more likely because you don't have write access in that directory.

Comment: I am administrator myself and have all permissions...

Comment: Well, maybe the path is wrong, then. Look at the output of `strcat(matlabroot, filesep, 'toolbox', filesep, 'local', filesep, 'classpath.txt')` and go check whether that file exists and you have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was facing the same, but solved this :

step1 : copying the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar file to the c:/programfile/matlab/R2012aStudent/toolbox/local

step2: In the "Please give the full path to the MySQL Java Connector (jar file) :" just provide the file name which is  "mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"

no need to give the full path in my case because by default it checks the file in the "c:/programfile/matlab/R2012aStudent/toolbox/local " folder